# how to save multiple canvases from a page

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, canvas

I have a page in which i have multiple canvases. I have a function that allows me to save each canvas one at a time. This function looks like this:

```
<button onclick="download()">Download</button>
<script>
    function download() {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = "pass.jpg";
        link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
        link.click();
    }
</script>
```

This is ok if a have maximum 10 canvases, but if my page has 200 canvases to download it would be a problem to click 200 buttons to download them all.
I tried to make a function that would save all the canvases from the page at once but it's not quite working. Here is my code:

```
<button onclick="download()">Download</button>
<script>
    function download() {
        var images = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var srcList = [];
        var i = 0;

        setInterval(function() {
            if (images.length > i) {
                srcList.push(images[i].src);
                var link = document.createElement("a");
                link.id = i;
                link.download = "pass.jpg";
                link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
                link.click();
                i++;
            }
        }, 1500);
    }
</script>
```

How can i modify this code to get the result i want?

Comment: I don't see where you ever select more than a single element...?

Comment: `setInterval` to perform a normal loop, and with no `clearInterval`. Funny.

Comment: aren't all the canvases put in `srcList` ? i'm new at all this javascript functions and i don't know..this is what i have read on the internet.

Comment: @PHPglue no need to make fun of me. this is my first time working with functions in javascript and all i know is self taught from the internet, so sorry if i was to dumb and didn't understand how this works. that is why i asked here maybe some of you can help me understand what i did wrong

Comment: You should just loop for something like `var canvases = document.querySelectorAll('canvas'); for(var i=0,l=canvases.length; i<l; i++){ var canvas = canvases[i]; /* other code */ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change **getElementById** to **getElementsByTagName** to get all canvas elements in array. 
And add clearInterval to stop the loop as mentiond by @PHPglue

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
var srcList = [];
var i = 0;

var timer = setInterval(function(){
    if(images.length > i){
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        srcList.push(images[i].src);
        link.id = i;
        link.download = "pass.jpg";
        link.href = images[i].toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
        link.click();
        i++;
    } else {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
},1500);
```

Comment: this works perfectly for what i need. thank you for your help. i have one more question, is it possible to save them in a archive? just to know if i should start looking how i can do that or not.

Comment: Try some of javascript zip libraries, like https://github.com/Stuk/jszip to create an archive